# Location of Suspend after Idle Setting In Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, suspend

I was playing with my Linux Mint settings and made it so the computer would suspend after it was idle for an hour.  It turns out suspending is broken.

Anyone know where was that setting located at?  I can't remember where I changed it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it was in Power Management.

[image]